# C# How i can expand an item in a listview to get multiple line with a new column in windows application

Tags: c#, mysql

Recently i worked with a ListView(details view) in c#.I want to implement the behavior when i select an item it expand with multiple line also with a new column.Where expanded line data come from MySql db.That means selected line have a connection with Mysql Db.

Is it possible to extend list view item with multiline column with multiple line?If so, is there a good resource that I can use to help me?

Comment: May be you need to embed Data Grid inside it. So that you can have columns in it. If you take a look at Windows Explorer, it has an listview. if you select details, then multiple column appears which is a grid.

Answer (score 0):

The system ListView does not support that. What you need is a combination of treeview and listview, usually called a TreeListView.

Search for TreeListView on google and you will get many such controls, some free, some commercial.

Comment: Please give me a link that can healp me

Comment: http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=9&gs_id=q&xhr=t&q=treelistview  This should give you tons of links.